# How can I get the Index of a ViewResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I'm attempting to create a Unit Test in which I can validate a select query.
I created a Fake Database and added the Email and Username into it.
I am unable to access the Email property of the ViewResult

When trying to use an index on a ViewResult I get the error

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

The action that grabs that information is correct and I can verify this by using the debugger on Visual Studio 2015. I am being returned an ActionResult which I then learned I had to cast to ViewResult.

Inside the Debugger I see

returnedResult -> Model -> [0] -> Email

```
        var fakeDb = new FakeApplicationDbContext();
        fakeDb.FoundInformation = new FakeDbSet<FoundInformation>();
        var foundInformation = new FoundInformation { Email = "Test@Email.com", Username = "User1" };
        var foundInformation2 = new FoundInformation { Email = "Test2@Email.com", Username = "User2" };
        fakeDb.FoundInformation.Add(foundInformation);
        fakeDb.FoundInformation.Add(foundInformation2);


        FoundInformationController foundInformationController = new FoundInformationController(fakeDb);
        var returnedResult = (ViewResult)foundInformationController.Details(new 
            Search { SearchTerm = "User2" });
        var foundInfoEmail = returnedResult.Model[0].Email;
```

The error I'm having is in the line

`var foundInfoEmail = returnedResult.Model[0].Email;`

How would I go about grabbing that Email to assert it's correct?

Comment: That's right. The type of `Model` is object. If you expect it to be some *specific* type you probably ought to assert that and then cast to that type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess I don't really understand how to do that. I tried toList but that doesn't work either

Comment: can you share `FoundInformtaionController.Details` method OR what type of `Model` is using in `Details View/ViewResult`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `Model` to desired type and access that email property.

for example if you returning List or array of object in your Details View.

You can access that property like

```
var returnedResult = (ViewResult)foundInformationController.Details(new 
        Search { SearchTerm = "User2" });
// if you return List then use like below and if you return an array then cast into array rather then list.
var model = returnResult.Model as List<Type of object Your return in Result> ;
var foundInfoEmail = model[0].Email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a try returnedResult.Model.ToList()[0].Email?

Comment: > object does not contain a definition for `ToList`